# How to disable vue draggable placeholder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I am currently doing a website builder, where user can drag and drop to add element.

The drag and drop works well, but what i want is, how can i disable/hide the drop placeholder in the target container ?

[image]

As show in the image, whenever I hover on a container, it will show a copy of my dragging element by default, which I don't want.

Here is my code :

```
<template>
<div style="display : flex;">
    <div id="dragArea">
        <draggable
            class="dragArea list-group"
            :list="list1"
            :group="{ name: 'item', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
            :clone="cloneItem"
            @change="log"
        >
            <div class="list-group-item" v-for="element in list1" :key="element.id">{{ element.name }}</div>
        </draggable>
    </div>

    <div id="dropArea">
        <draggable class="dragArea list-group" :list="list2" group="item" @change="log">
            <div class="list-group-item" v-for="element in list2" :key="element.id">{{ element.name }}</div>
        </draggable>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Script :

```
<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
let idGlobal = 8;

export default {
    name: "custom-clone",
    display: "Custom Clone",
    order: 3,
    components: {
        draggable,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            hover : false,
            list1: [
                { name: "cloned 1", id: 1 },
                { name: "cloned 2", id: 2 },
            ],
            list2: [

            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        log: function(evt) {
            window.console.log(evt);
        },
        cloneItem({ name, id }) {
            return {
                id: idGlobal++,
                name: name
            };
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

On each of your `<draggable>` components within your `<template>`, you can set the `ghost-class` prop to a CSS class that hides the drop placeholder (ie. "ghost", or "dragging element" as you called it) using `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`.

For example:

- In your `<template>`:

  ```
   <draggable ghost-class="hidden-ghost">
  ```
- and in the `<style>` section of your Vue Single File Component, or in the corresponding stylesheet:

  ```
   .hidden-ghost {
       display: none;
   }
  ```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nclarosa/gn5L4j09/211/)**

The `ghost-class` prop internally sets the SortableJS `ghostClass` option (see all the options [here](https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs#options)).  The ability to modify these SortableJS options as Vue.Draggable props is available as of [Vue.Draggable v2.19.1](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/releases/tag/v2.19.1).